# javascript accessing 2d array element directly by value

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a 2d array containing data like the following:

```
[ 
  [ 'name', 'mike' ],
  [ 'type', 'person' ],
  [ 'age', '24' ]
]
```

I need to access the value of the second element of the inner array, based on the value of the first element in the inner array.

So basically I want to specify "name" and in return, receive the value "mike". How can I accomplish this without looping through the entire array?

Comment: You can't do it without looping through the array (although you can stop the loop when you find the correct value). If at all possible, you should consider using objects instead.

Comment: why don't you use an object? `{ name: "mike", type: "person", age: 24 }`

Comment: This is what objects are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Juhana said, use objects:

```
obj = { 
  name: 'mike',
  type: 'person',
  age: 24
};
```

Then you can access the value of name by `obj.name`.